# difference between frontend quote and admin quote

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

In magento when any customer adds product to cart or when admin adds a product to any customer's cart from backend then the values are inserted in sales_flat_quote table. Does anybody have idea that how we can differentiate between frontend and backend's data by looking into the table's data (if both are booked with same customer id) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the column name called `remote_ip`, that filed is generally helps us to find out where the quote was created from.

Usually, front end quote will have `ip address` in that column where admin quote will have null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if I set add product into cart from backend and then add manually the IP address then will that updated to frontend's customer cart?

Comment: And do you know the location of file where this remote_ip is set?

Comment: Above answer is entirely based on your initial question. You should ask another question for that. Since admin and frontend are treated differently in magento.

Comment: Alright got the file location. Thanks. For future users its in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php

Comment: done ....... :)